# VB.Net - Failed to enable constraints. One or more rows contain values violating non-null, unique, or foreign-key constraints

Tags: vb.net, dataset

I am creating a Library Automation System using VB.Net. In the book adding form (UI) I want to add Book Author(a field in tblBookDetails. But Adding Book Author is another UI. To add book author in book adding UI, I have a combo box to populate all `authorFirstName` but the value member should be `authorID`. I want to populate Book Author names from BookAuthor table. While run I got the following error `Failed to enable constraints. One or more rows contain values violating non-null, unique, or foreign-key constraints.`

**tblBookAuthor and tblBookDetails schema**

```
tblBookAuthor(authorID, authorFirstName) // authorID - PK

tblBookDetails(accessionNo, authorId, title) // authorID - FK
```

**This is my code**

```
Private Sub frmAddBook_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        SqlDataAdapter1.Fill(DataSet51, "tblBookAuthor") // Highlighted as error
        dt = DataSet51.Tables("tblBookAuthor")

    End Sub
```

**Update**

**Additional Code for getId for Author Name**

```
Private Sub cboBookAuthor_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmbAuthorId.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 0 To DataSet51.Tables("tblBookAuthor").Rows.Count - 1
        If cboBookAuthor.Text = DataSet51.Tables("tblBookAuthor").Rows(i).Item(1) Then
            txtBookAuthorID.Text = DataSet51.Tables("tblBookAuthor").Rows(i).Item(0)
            Exit For
        End If

    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: What does the Select statement look like? If you bind your combo box you can set Display member and Value member.

Comment: Based on the name, it would appear that that table is for a many-to-many relationship between books and authors. Assuming it is, did you populate the tables containing the primary keys for books and authors? If not, there's your foreign key violations right there.  If you need to be able get foreign key values without getting the corresponding primary keys, don't use a `DataSet`. Instead, call `GetData` instead of `Fill` to get a standalone `DataTable`, That way, there's no foreign key constraints to violate.

Comment: @jmcilhinney, That is correct. there is many-to-many relationship. How can I do that?

Comment: @Mary, that is correct. But the error high lights `SqlDataAdapter1.Fill(DataSet51, "tblBookAuthor")` this line

Comment: You're asking me how to call a method? Come on. You know how to call a method.

Comment: @jmcilhinney, I did not ask how cal a method. How to do your suggested way.

Comment: My suggested way was to call the `GetData` method instead of the `Fill` method. My solution is to call a specific method. If you're asking how to implement my solution then you're asking how to call that method.

Comment: But, `SqlDataAdapter1` does not have `GetData` method only `Fill`

Comment: Ah, sorry. I was thinking that you were using a typed `DataSet` and a table adapter. In that case, just don't create a `DataSet`. Create a `DataTable` only and then pass that to `Fill`.

Comment: How to do I am confused

Comment: I believe it would be like this `Dim dt = New DataTable("tblBookAuthor")` and then
`SqlDataAdapter1.Fill(dt)`

Comment: But does not success. It does not populate the combo Box